# For loop incrementing time by 45 minutes

Tags: php, for-loop

I know i can do a normal loop with whole integers like this

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
   echo $i;
}
```

**Problem:**
I want to loop through a loop not with whole numbers but with <strike>floats</strike> times ( 45 minutes ). I want the results to be like this:

```
0.45
1.30
2.15
3.00
3.45
...
```

Is there any helper function in PHP to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried it? The PHP documentation says nothing about not supporting floats in `for` loops.

Comment: Are those supposed to be times?

Comment: Multiply by 100, loop and divide again.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes this are supposed to be times.

Comment: ... Then why are you pretending that they're floats?

Comment: A minute isn't 1/100 of an hour, so you don't want to add .45 each loop.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I am quite new to this and that was my first thought of doing it..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reading the comments and seeing that you actually want to work with times, you can even use a `DateTime` object inside a for loop

Here is some example code:

```
for (
    $d = new DateTime('00:00'), // Initialise DateTime object .
    $i = new DateInterval('PT45M'); // New 45 minute date interval
    $d->format('H') < 10; // While hours (24h) less than 10
    $d->add($i) // Add the interval to the DateTime object
)
{
    echo $d->format("H:i\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use floats in the loop. `$i++` in the final part of the loop means to increment the counter by `1`.  Simply change that to `0.45` and you are done.

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i=$i + 0.45)
{
   echo $i;
}
```

// Edit

As many people have pointed out, there is inherent issue with floating point precision.  The above example *should* work for small numbers  `$i < 100` but there may be issues when numbers become large.

Comment: @Baba: It can't be fixed, because the question itself is broken.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams .. i agree with you

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i += 0.45)
{
   echo $i;
}
```

something like this?

Comment: You have same code error with `Kami` i suspect copy and paste

Comment: Sorry, but this code don't have any error, it is right syntax :)

Comment: For educational purpose just see http://codepad.org/9D4pgW63 look at line `776` in the output

Comment: Ouuu.. I understand, thank you, i'm forgot about this php calculation feature :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on float numbers for that. Reason is rounding.

What you normally do is use an int, and then divide.

```
for($i=0, $j=0; $i < $MAX; $i += 45, $j = $i / 100)
{
    echo $j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use

```
for($i=0.0;$i<10.0;$i=$i+0.45)
{
   echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd be using floating point values to control the loop itself, especially given their propensity for imprecision :-)

Since you appear to have a formula in mind, you can simply use the formula within the loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $ < 10; $i++) {
   $num = 0.45 + $i * 0.85;
   echo $num;
}
```

This allows the loop to be controlled with an integer and simply gives you the floating point value based on that integer.

Answer (score -1):

maybe like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    echo $i * 0.45."<br />";
}
```